# Adobe Reader DC fails to write PDF even though real printer installed

Tags: 18.04, printing, adobe-reader

When I try to print a file from Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, I get this error message:

*Before you can perform print-related tasks such as page setup or printing a document, you need to install a printer.*

I have a printer connected by ethernet that works for all other applications on this machine.

System Info ------------------------------------------

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC
Continious Release | Version 2018.011.20063

Installed Plugins:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\plug_ins\AcroForm.api  
    Version: 18.11.20055.290043  
    Creation Date: 2018/09/12  
    Creation Time: 10:32:24 PM  
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\plug_ins\DigSig.api  
    Version: 18.11.20055.290043  
    Creation Date: 2018/09/12  
    Creation Time: 10:32:24 PM  
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\plug_ins\IA32.api  
    Version: 18.11.20055.290043  
    Creation Date: 2018/09/12  
    Creation Time: 10:32:24 PM  
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\plug_ins\PPKLite.api  
    Version: 18.11.20055.290043  
    Creation Date: 2018/09/12  
    Creation Time: 10:32:24 PM  
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\plug_ins\Spelling.api  
    Version: 18.11.20055.290043  
    Creation Date: 2018/09/12  
    Creation Time: 10:32:24 PM
```

---

The installation finished but something is not right.

```
$ acroread  
acroread: command not found  
  
$ apt list --installed | grep acro  
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.  
anacron/bionic,now 2.3-24 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: The tutorial on this page here seems to get Adobe Reader (not DC) to install, and be able to print: https://linuxnightly.com/install-adobe-acrobat-pdf-reader-ubuntu/ See option 2

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Adobe Reader DC. Adobe Reader DC is a different app than the traditional Adobe Reader. Follow these simple instructions.

In terminal:

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core libxml2:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libatk-adaptor:i386
```

Then download the reader deb package:

```
wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

[Reference](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Comment: I will follow your instructions but I'm confused. You say that I need to install Adobe Acrobat reader. What is Adobe Acrobat Reader DC if not that?

Comment: The cloud-based "DC" (Document Cloud) is a different app than the traditional Adobe Reader.

Comment: Ah...I didn't know what DC meant. Thanks. Installation in progress ...

Comment: installation completed, but something is not right. See addition to original post please.